# Is it possible to remove post from facebook wall from my android application

Tags: android, facebook, android-facebook

I have a typical condition where user's post should remain on facebook wall for 2 to 3 days , after that it should be removed .I am using facebook sdk 3.0 .I really want some guidance regarding how to do that , because i didn't find any post like this .

I appreciate and welcome any kind of suggestions .
Thank you in advance for paying interest in my question .

Answer (score 1):

Here's how to delete an object through the Graph API: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/deleting/

You can have a Timer/Alarm that launches a background service that checks for posts that are 2-3 days old and delete them.

Answer (score 1):

As stated [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/android/3.0/Request), `public Request(Session session, String graphPath, Bundle parameters, HttpMethod httpMethod)` is used for this:

> Depending on the httpMethod parameter, the object at the graph path
>   may be retrieved, created, or deleted.